# What happens if a file/folder owner gets deleted?

Tags: permissions

What happens when I delete a group wich is owner of certain folders and files? Who become the owner then?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wich` to `which` and `become` to `becomes`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each user has a unique number, called a *uid*. Each group has a unique number, called a *gid*. It's the *uid* and *gid* that gets stored as owners of files, not the username or groupname.

The mapping between username and *uid* is in `/etc/passwd`, and the mapping between groupname and *gid* is in `/etc/group` (unless you've set up some other form of database for this).

When you use `ls -l` to list files, `ls` will query `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to find the corresponding username and groupname for the file ownership.

When you remove a group, you just remove the mapping between groupname and *gid* in `/etc/group`, nothing happens to the files this group owned, they'll still be owned by the same *gid*, but since that group doesn't exist anymore, `ls -l` will print the *gid* instead of a groupname, and no one will have access to the file via its group ownership anymore.

If you create a new group and it gets assigned the same *gid* as the one you deleted, the files will then be owned by that group.

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Permissions

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are stored on the filesystem if that filesystem supports them.

There is no direct connection between the available users or groups on a particular machine with the permissions of a file/folder.

If you delete a group or a user the permissions simply remain the same, you have 2 commands that you can use to change user and group permission, they both require `sudo`:

- `chgrp` to change the group for a file/folder
- `chown` to change the owner for a file/folder

for example

```
sudo chgrp myfellas file.txt
```

or

```
sudo chown -R jon music/
```